# Enhance performance for threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I have an app with a start button that calls a long running time function. In order
to add a Stop button I've added a thread for this function to avoid the UI freezes and be able to stop the processing in anytime.

The code without threading in average takes 12 minutes to complete the processing, but with threading in the way I have below
takes 4 times more. Below is shown the code for the start button where is called the function "LongRunningFunction" . The function
needs a string argument to work "LongRunningFunction(Somestring)".

I've tested with Task.Run and Task.Factory.StartNew but it happens the same with both methods.

Is there an alternative way to set a thread for my case that doesn't affect too much the performance?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // Create the token source.
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(()=> LongRunningFunction(Somestring, cts.Token), cts.Token);            
        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningFunction(Somestring, cts.Token), cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default); 
    }
    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Processing cancelled");
        }
    }
    public void LongRunningFunction(string String, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //Long running processing
        //...
        MessageBox.Show("Processing finished");
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The only what I changed is the way I declare the function and added an if statement inside the while loop
that is inside the function. Is like below:

- The CancelationToken was added in order to be able to stop the processing when Stop button is pressed.

Without thread I declare the function like this:

```
public void LongRunningFunction(string String) 
{ 
    while (condition)
    {
        //My code within While loop
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Processing finished");
}
```

and with Thread I define the function like this:

```
public void LongRunningFunction(string String, CancellationToken token) 
{ 
    while (condition)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }       
        //My code within While loop
    }
    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Processing finished");
    }       
}
```

**Update2:**
Inside LongRunningFunction() is called another function that prints the lines. Is like below.

```
    public void LongRunningFunction(string fileName, CancellationToken token)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@outputfile, true, Encoding.UTF8, 4096);

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
            List<string> buffer1 = new List<string>();

            SoapHexBinary hex = new SoapHexBinary();

            while (chunk.Length > 0)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested) // ### For Cancel Thread ###
                {
                    break;
                }   // ### For Cancel Thread ###    

                    chunk = reader.ReadBytes(1024);

                    foreach (byte data in chunk)
                    {
                        if (somecondition)
                        {
                            buffer.Add(data);                           
                        }
                        else if (other condition)
                        {
                            buffer.Add(data);
                            PrintFunction(buffer, hex, outputfile, writer); // Print Line
                        }
                        else if (some other condition)
                        {
                            buffer.Add(data);
                        }
                    }                   
            }           
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Processing finished");
            }

        }

        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.Dispose();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }       
    private void PrintFunction(List<byte> buffer, SoapHexBinary hex, string outputfile, StreamWriter writer)
    {
            if (buffer.Count > 0)
            {
                if (buffer.Count >= lowlimit)
                {
                    hex.Value = buffer.ToArray();
                    string Register = hex.ToString();

                    Regex pattern1 = new Regex(@"some pattern");

                    if (pattern1.IsMatch(Register))
                    {
                        Match l1 = Regex.Match(Register, @"somepattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                        writer.Write("{0}|{1}|{2}", Convert.ToInt32(l1.Groups[1].ToString(), 16), l1.Groups[2].Value, l1.Groups[3].Value);
                        Match l2 = Regex.Match(Register, @"otherpattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                        if (l2.Success)
                        {
                            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(l2.Groups[2].ToString(), pattern2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled))
                            {
                                //Some foreach code
                            }
                            foreach (Match x in Regex.Matches(var, @"pattern"))
                            {
                                //come code
                            }
                            writer.WriteLine("," + String.Join(",", var1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            buffer.Clear();
    }
```

**Update3:**
 Hi bebosh,

I still have doubts how to apply in my function, the way you define the delegate in your example function.

My function looks like this:

```
public void LongRunningFunction(string fileName)
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

It could be something like this or how?:

```
private void LongRunningFunction(string fileName)
{
    MethodInvoker action = delegate
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            // some code
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Running code on an extra thread instead of the UI thread should not decrease the performance four-fold (nor should it really increase the performance, as exactly the same work is being done, give or take the processing of a few window messages). What else did you change? What do you do with the `CancellationToken` that the original code didn't?

Comment: You should be using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` if the operation takes 12 minutes, not that that would cause the 4x slowdown that you're seeing.

Comment: Does your LongRunningFunction() update the UI by any chance (via using Dispatcher or any other mechanism)?. If not, I can't see how it would affect the performance at all.

Comment: Hello to all, Please see my original post below "Update". The CancelationToken was added in order to be able to stop the processing when Stop button is pressed since I've added a thread in order to add the stop button since without a thread when the processing is done the UI freezes and I wasn't able to stop it. The function doesn't update the UI, only saves lines to a output txt file.

Comment: Hi CodeCaster. The while is used to read a file than more than 2GB in chunks of 1024 bytes, then the loop runs about 2 million times.

Comment: How about synchronization? Do you use locks or anything similar when writing lines to your file? Without knowing what the "My code within while loop" is, it's very hard to comment. Generally speaking, all things being equal, you shouldn't see this performance problem.

Comment: Hi kha. I'm not sure about how synchronization works. Inside the loop I use a stream writer to print lines one after another to the output file. The writer is called about 5 times for each chunk read.

Comment: Any chance at all you could paste the code that does the writing (using StreamWriter)? It may very well be that your code is inefficient and calling `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` two million times in a tight loop can have very negative impacts on the performance since it will mess with branch prediction.

Comment: Hi kha, please see how it looks the LongRunningFunction() and how is used the writer below Update2 in my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this code:

```
    bool Stop = false;
    Thread thread;

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = @"...\a.bin";
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => DoLongProcess(FileName)));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stop = true;
    }


    private void DoLongProcess(string file)
    {
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(file, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            int pos = 0;
            int length = (int)reader.BaseStream.Length;
            while (pos < length)
            {
                if (Stop)
                    thread.Abort();
                // using Invoke if you want cross UI objects
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    label1.Text = pos.ToString();
                });
                pos += sizeof(int);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi bebosh. I've added a TestButton and used your code, but how to addapt the estructure of your example to run my function with the string argument and be able to use the stop button to cancel in any moment?

Comment: Thanks bebosh, please see my update3 in original post. I have still have doubts in how to apply you example in my function.

Comment: Hi bebosh, the issue is the function needs a string argument to be called. Is defined like "private void DoLongProcess(string file){..}". Then in StartButton_Click() should be called something like this "thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoLongProcess(filename)));" But I receive error when I do that in your code.

Comment: the error is "No overload for method 'DoLongProcess' takes one argument (CS1501)". I think maybe "ThreadStart(Function)" works fine, but "ThreadStart(Function(argument))" is not accepted.

Comment: Excellent bebosh, it Works this time with the fix you did. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

Bebosh's answer was good enough. To increase the performance further you can set the ThreadPriority of the "thread" by setting the ".Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal" right after setting the "thread.IsBackground = true;".

Answer (score -1):

use interrupting the thread

```
        Thread thread;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void StartButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            thread = new Thread(ExecuteLong);
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
                thread.Start());
            await task;
        }

        private void ExecuteLong()
        {
            try
            {
                // long task
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cancelled!");
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("finished");
        }

        private void CancelButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.thread.Interrupt();
        }
```

Comment: `var task = Task.Run(() => thread.Start()); await task;` This code doesn't made any kind of sense.